# NSButton is focus but don't have focus ring

Tags: macos, cocoa

I used default NSButton (Push) in Mac 10.8. It is focused (press space key, the action is done) but the focus ring doesn't show. I don't know why? Please shed me a light. Thanks

Comment: All controls in my app haven't the focus ring when it is focused.
However, there is a window which is normal. All of its controls have a focus ring when it is focused.

Comment: Which control set Focus ring is none --> see focus ring. Which control is set Focus ring is Default --> don't see focus ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the problem.
I have start a NSTimer in a queue block.
I just comment out it the issue is resolved.
I try to rewrite this code.